# dplyr: Using poly function to generate polynomial coefficients

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, poly

I want to append polynomial coefficient to data.frame as the example given below:

```
df1 <- 
  structure(list(
    Y = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 
          16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 
          16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
          8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -60L))

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Linear    = poly(x = Y, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)[ ,1]
  , Quadratic = poly(x = Y, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)[ ,2]  
  , Cubic     = poly(x = Y, degree = 3, raw = TRUE)[ ,3]
    )
```

I wonder if there is a concise method like this

```
df1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(poly(x = Y, degree = 3, raw = TRUE))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not exactly the way you were hoping, but close enough. I first convert the output of `poly` (a matrix) to a data.frame, then use `!!!` to splice the columns (turning each element of a list/data.frame into it's own argument). `setNames` is optional for renaming the columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(!!!as.data.frame(poly(x = .$Y, degree = 3, raw = TRUE))) %>%
  setNames(c("Y", "Linear", "Quadratic", "Cubic"))
```

**Result:**

```
    Y Linear Quadratic Cubic
1   4      4        16    64
2   4      4        16    64
3   4      4        16    64
4   4      4        16    64
5   4      4        16    64
6   8      8        64   512
7   8      8        64   512
8   8      8        64   512
9   8      8        64   512
10  8      8        64   512
11 16     16       256  4096
12 16     16       256  4096
13 16     16       256  4096
14 16     16       256  4096
15 16     16       256  4096
16 32     32      1024 32768
17 32     32      1024 32768
18 32     32      1024 32768
19 32     32      1024 32768
20 32     32      1024 32768
...
```

Comment: [Info on !!! here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), I had never seen it before. About 2/3 of the way down the page.

Comment: @zack It's part of a fairly new ecosystem of programming with dplyr that works well with other `tidyverse` functions. Also check `rlang`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, although I really like @useR's solution:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(data.frame(Y = unique(.$Y), poly(unique(.$Y), degree = 3, raw = TRUE)),
            by = c('Y' = 'Y')) %>% 
  setNames(c('Y', 'Linear', 'Quadratic', 'Cubic'))

    Y Linear Quadratic Cubic
1   4      4        16    64
2   4      4        16    64
3   4      4        16    64
4   4      4        16    64
5   4      4        16    64
6   8      8        64   512
7   8      8        64   512
8   8      8        64   512
9   8      8        64   512
10  8      8        64   512
11 16     16       256  4096
12 16     16       256  4096
13 16     16       256  4096
14 16     16       256  4096
15 16     16       256  4096
16 32     32      1024 32768
17 32     32      1024 32768
18 32     32      1024 32768
19 32     32      1024 32768
20 32     32      1024 32768
```

Comment: Don't really need `by = c('Y' = 'Y')` since it's the only mutual column

Comment: True, I've gotten into the habit of always including both sides in my code just because I've found it to make code more readable, in general. Still a good thing to point out, though.

Comment: you can also just type `by = 'Y'` since they have the same name, but I get your point of keeping it consistent.